# Does time limit affect monster health?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Looking through my investigations, I have a number of investigations for the same monster but with different time limits (50 minutes, 30 minutes, 15 minutes). Is the 15-minute monster weaker than the 50-minute monster or do they have the same health?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time limit does not affect monster health. Outside of event quests, only multi-monster quests affect monster health, reducing the health of every target monster by around 30%.

Comment: I think you wanted to say that their health is reduced down to 30% and not reduced by 30%

Comment: I don't know the exact number, but it felt like 30-40% less health.

Comment: I'm sure I read it somewhere that it is reduced down to ~30%. This would match with my experience far more than a reduction by 30% (experience based on "Sapphire Star Guidance" and the respective solo kills
)

Comment: Wow good to know, I've avoided optional multi-monster missions because I cannot dedicate the time needed. Going to have to try some knowing this.